# ExtJs Border Layout Hide All Regions On Click

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

Hi I am new to ExtJs and am working on a project with a border layout. I want to create an event so that when the center region is clicked or receives focus all other regions collapse. What type of listener would I have to create and where would I put it?

Answer (score 1):

You can add an event listener to your center region. The event you're looking for is 'focus'.

There are multiple ways to get references to the regions of the border layout. I've listed one below. Once you have the reference you can call its collapse method.

```
xtype: 'container',
itemId: 'mycontainer',  
layout: {
    type: 'border' 
},
items: [{
    xtype: 'panel',
    title: 'My Center Panel',
    region: 'center',
    listeners:{
        focus: function( pan, event, eOpts ){
            var container = pan.up('#mycontainer');
            container.down('panel[region=north]').collapse();
            container.down('panel[region=east]').collapse();
        }
    }
},{
    xtype: 'panel',
    title: 'My North Panel',
    region: 'north'
},{
    xtype: 'panel',
    title: 'My East Panel',
    region: 'east'     
}]
```